# Ruby's :yields:

Tags: ruby

I was looking through some tab-completions that were automatically set up for my editor, and I found one where y was mapped to:

```
:yields: arguments
```

**What** is this syntax called, **when**, **where**, **how** and for **what**  is this used?

Comment: I've never seen this, and can't seem to find an example of it. Are you sure you have it right, and that it's for Ruby?

Comment: Can you provide more complete example? AFAIK, this is not valid ruby syntax. But it can be related to _yield_ operator: http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/06/ruby-yield.html

Comment: `:yields:` (for RDOC) sounds like the third person singular. As opposed to the second person singular Matz [generally prefers](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/82759#145502) for commands themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the many directives supported by the RDoc documentation tool. [It is used to document the arguments that get passed to a block](http://RDoc.RubyForge.Org/RDoc/Parser/Ruby.html).